# Toggle Year when it comes January or December with jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

Have written a code for toggling months and years like you see in the windows clock when you click on it on right bottom corner. I just want to achieve the upper part highlighted in red. No calender under it.

[image]

I have achieved all of it but there is glitch. When you go to the future months it changes the year in December. It should change the year on January. Same with when you go back. You can see live example here... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omerblink/6TuQ7/)

Here is my jQuery Code:

```
    var $months = [
    "",
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"];

var d = new Date();
var $m = d.getMonth() + 1;
var $y = d.getFullYear();


$('.history-months').click(function () {
    var month_num = $('.months').attr('month-count');
    var year_num = $('.years').text();
    var history_month = parseFloat(month_num) - 1;
    $('.months').attr("month-count", history_month);
    $('.months').text($months[history_month]);
    if (month_num < 3) {
        $('.months').attr("month-count", 13);
        var history_year = parseFloat(year_num) - 1;
        $('.years').text(history_year);
    }
});
$('.future-months').click(function () {
    var month_num = $('.months').attr('month-count');
    var year_num = $('.years').text();
    var future_month = parseFloat(month_num) + 1;
    $('.months').attr("month-count", future_month);
    $('.months').text($months[future_month]);
    if (month_num > 10) {
        $('.months').attr("month-count", 0);
        var history_year = parseFloat(year_num) + 1;
        $('.years').text(history_year);
    }
});

$('.months').text($months[$m]).attr('month-count', $m);
$('.years').text($y);
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="history-months">&LT;</a>

<span class="months-years">
    <span class="months"></span>
    <span class="years"></span>
</span>

<a href="#" class="future-months">&GT;</a>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Omer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the solution myself :p

I thought i should share with the world as well :)

Just edit my condition a bit:

```
$('.future-months').click(function() {
    var month_num = $('.months').attr('month-count');
    var year_num = $('.years').text();
    var future_month = parseFloat(month_num) + 1;
    if (future_month > 12) {
         future_month = 1;
         year_num = parseFloat(year_num) + 1;
    }
    $('.months').attr("month-count", future_month);
    $('.months').text($months[future_month]);
    $('.years').text(year_num);
});

$('.history-months').click(function() {
    var month_num = $('.months').attr('month-count');
    var year_num = $('.years').text();
    var history_month = parseFloat(month_num) - 1;
    if (history_month < 1) {
         history_month = 12;
         year_num = parseFloat(year_num) - 1;
    }
    $('.months').attr("month-count", history_month);
    $('.months').text($months[history_month]);
    $('.years').text(year_num);
});
```

Hope it will be helpful for others :)

Omer